# how to plot different stats for every year

Tags: python, matplotlib, time, statistics

I have a dataset where over 5 years, for each person, i have 3 stats (for, against, neutral) which are represented as percentage.
Do you have any ideas on how to plot this over time for each person ?
I tought of a pie chart for each year, is it good idea ?

year|x|y|z|uniq_key

2011|0.005835365238989241|0.7761263149278178|0.21803831983319283|P1
2012|0.009289549431275945|0.7361277645833669|0.2545826859853564|P1
2013|0.008078032727124805|0.7392018809692821|0.2527200863035934|P1
2011|0.0069655450457009405|0.7275518410866034|0.26548261386769734|P2
2012|0.008719188605542267|0.7855644106925562|0.20571640070190217|P2
2013|0.011938649525870312|0.8028230127919557|0.1852383376821743|P2

Comment: what exactly you are looking for, show some sample

Answer (score 0):

A line chart for each stat with year on the x-axis, percentage on the y-axis and a line for each user.